# Why APP is exiting on back button Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, button, titanium, back

**app.js**

```
if (osname === 'android') {
    Window = require('ui/handheld/android/SignIn');
}
else {
    Window = require('ui/handheld/SignIn');
}

new Window().open();
```

**SignIn.js**

```
function SignIn() {
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow();
    //Some design and sign-in validation code
    ...
    var StatusMain = require('/ui/handheld/android/StatusMain');
    new StatusMain(global_vars).open();
    return self;
}
```

**StatusMain.js**

```
function StatusMain(global_vars) {
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow();
        return self;
}
```

On **StatusMain.js**, screen When I click on device's **back button** APP exits instead of going back on SignIn.js screen

Any help will be highly appreciable!

Thanks in advance,

Mohsin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can handle back button event like this in your code

```
window.addEventListener('android:back', function(){
    // close your current window
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you set the (Android specific) exitOnClose property on false when creating the new window:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-exitOnClose

> exitOnClose : Boolean
>   CREATION-ONLY
>
> Boolean value indicating if the application should exit when the Android Back button is > > pressed while the window is being shown.
>
> You can only set this as a createWindow({...}) option. Setting it after window creation > has no effect.

### StatusMain.js

```
function StatusMain(global_vars) {
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        exitOnClose: false
    });
        return self;
}
```

That should do the trick. Although the default value is false, it seems that your issue has something to do with that. I recommend experimenting with settings this property to true/false.

Word of advise, you should also test your app on a device if you haven't done so already. My experience with the Android emulators is rather inconsistent at some points.

Answer (score 1):

StatusMain is a lightweight window. It doesn't create new Android activity, instead it shares with SignIn window activity. That's why your app closes when press back button. You need to create a heavyweight window to (specify fullscreen or navBarHidden properties) StatusMain window.

Answer (score 0):

Set the modal property for the new window to true.

```
function StatusMain(global_vars) {
        var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        modal: true
    });
    return self;
}
```